# Internet browser icon changed to Lookout icon

Tags: updates, browser, app-icons

My internet browser icon has changed from a picture of earth to Lookout icon. Has anyone else had this happen? Why?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's an icon from Lookout security. Did you install Lookout before? Was there any system/app update before this? It might be possible that this is an update to AT&T user, since [they are partners](https://www.lookout.com/partners) and [they preload Android devices with Lookout apps](http://www.androidcentral.com/lookout-security-coming-att-android-phones).

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that the system got the app icon misconfigured. It happened to me before, a simple on off procedure could fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CBA110's answer, try clearing cache on TW launcher and possibly SystemUI. Under `Settings >> Application Manager >> All apps >> "TouchWiz home" >> Clear cache` and possibly Clear data as well, but that might reset your homescreen arrangement.